# Hide show modal using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to hide/ show a modal using an `axios` post. I get the error, **Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined**

Any ideas?

```
// dispatch to hide modal
hide() {
    this.props.dispatch(hideModal());
}


// dispatch to show modal
show() {
    this.props.dispatch(
        showError({
            type: 'SHOW_MODAL',
            modalType: 'SHOW_LOADING',
            modalProps: {
                onClose: hideModal,
                text: 'Please complete all fields',
            },
        })
    );
}

submitForm(UserDetails) {
    this.show();

    axios
        .post('http://localhost:3001/api/users', UserDetails)
        .then(function(response) {
            this.hide();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not `this` within the function of axios.
You could try this:

```
submitForm(UserDetails) {
    var self = this;
    self.show();

    axios
        .post('http://localhost:3001/api/users', UserDetails)
        .then(function(response) {
            self.hide();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

these can also be bound within your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
}
```

then you can use them like you're doing right now. the latter works atleast with arrow (=>) functions, with normal functions i'm not sure how `this` references so with your code, i'd go with the first answer.

Comment: I don't think that the second solution you propose would work, since here it's the `axios` `this` that causes the issue

Comment: I agree but i do think it Will reference correctly IF you use arrow function as I said, but with regular function() it wont work...

Answer (score 0):

Bind hide() method in your element's constructor.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.hide = this.hide.bind(this);
    }
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

It's `this` point question.

```
hide = () => {
  this.props.dispatch(...); // 1
}

show = () => {
  this.props.dispatch(...); // 1
}

submitForm = (UserDetails) => {
    this.show();

    axios
        .post('http://localhost:3001/api/users', UserDetails)
        .then((response) => {
          this.hide();  // 2
        })

 }
```

the mark 1 place `this` point correctly because `xxx = () => {}` syntax from to es7.

and the mark 2 place `this` use arrow function so point correctly.